# How to open a video file in Windows using the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, video, vlc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mplayer

So I am learning the Linux/Ubuntu command line. One of the things I want to be able to do is to use the Ubuntu terminal (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to open video files (mp4) on my computer (Windows 10).

I have tried VLC and MPlayer, but when I run `vlc filename` or `mplayer filename`, it gives me a very long error. It seems like it is running, but only shows text and then gives a long error.

Comment: So when you say that `vlc filename` "seems like it runs", does the VLC window itself open before it gives you the error?  If you type just `vlc`, does it open (without a video, of course)?  When you specify a filename, are you specifying a path, or have you already `cd`'d to the directory with the video from within Ubuntu?

Comment: "*it gives me a very long error*" - this is essential information when asking how to get past an error. Edit your question and include the complete error.  Also can you add some additional clarity: are you trying to open a *Windows* application from Ubuntu? Not possible. If VLC is installed in Ubuntu, do you have a functioning window manager or desktop environment? Desktops and GUI apps are not yet officially supported on WSL and won't work without a lot of wrangling. Also, are you aware that VLC is available on Windows?

Comment: @Nmath *"are you trying to open a Windows application from Ubuntu? Not possible.*"  Not sure what you mean here - That's completely doable under WSL.  I'm pretty certain that the OP is trying to open a file with the Windows version of VLC, but I agree that the question needs a *lot* of clarification.

Comment: Navigate to the directory where you keep your video files and try running `vlc.exe filename` instead of `vlc filename`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that out-of-the-box ([official docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-windows-tools-from-linux)):

> WSL can run Windows tools directly from the WSL command line using
> `[tool-name].exe`. For example, `notepad.exe`.
>
> Applications run this way have the following properties:
>
> - Retain the working directory as the WSL command prompt (for the most part -- exceptions are explained below).
> - Have the same permission rights as the WSL process.
> - Run as the active Windows user.
> - Appear in the Windows Task Manager as if directly executed from the CMD prompt.
>
> Windows executables run in WSL are handled similarly to native Linux
> executables -- piping, redirects, and even backgrounding work as expected.

If something fails, you could post a pastebin of the error/s, plus the output of

```
$ which vlc
$ which mplayer
$ pwd
```

Also, try other Win commands, as e.g. in the link above, to see if they work.